# Wie übersetzt man "kettle" in "Police has many protesters kettled"?

Tags: translation

Das Wort gibt es als Verb und Adjektiv (siehe Titel). Es wird im selben Zusammenhang auch als  Substantiv benutzt:

> Fifty protesters are in the kettle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

kettle

- Verb: einkesseln
- Substantiv: Einkesselung, Kessel

Ich würde die folgende Übersetzung wählen:

> Fünfzig Demonstranten sind eingekesselt.

oder vielleicht:

> Fünfzig Demonstranten befinden sich im Kessel der Polizei.

aber das hielte ich eher für zweite Wahl.

Comment: +1, zur Verwendung des Substantivs siehe auch http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Kessel

Answer (score 1):

Heisst hier auch Kessel und kesseln.

Comment: *Kesseln* klingt für mich eher nach [Werner](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_%28Comic%29) ;-)